# childNodeWithName of custom type is returning nil

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

So I'm trying to use childNodeWithName to find a specific object of a custom class in didBeginContact, but it doesn't seem to see it.  The println statement returns IAmAPortal1, but it doesn't find it when I try to search for it.

```
if(A == firstPort && B != playerCategory){
    println(aBody!.name)

    if let p1 = world.childNodeWithName("IAmAPortal1") as? Portal{
        if p1.portalEstablished == false {
            p1.portalEstablished = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SpriteKit childNodeWithName can't find existing node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25581738/spritekit-childnodewithname-cant-find-existing-node)

Comment: what is Portal? a subclass of SKNode?

Comment: class Portal:SKSpriteNode {

Comment: try `println(world.childNodeWithName("IAmAPortal1"))` (or set a breakpoint) to see if the node is actually a portal.

Comment: fixed it.  had to change it to     if var p1: Portal = world.childNodeWithName("IAmAPortal1") as? Portal{